# select OneToMany query jpql

Tags: java, jpql

I create two entities Idee and Avis which they have OneToMany relation . i want to select the collection in Idee . i try this but it doesn't work i show all the table of avis .

SELECT avis FROM idee i JOIN i.avis avis

how can i correct it ?

this is Idee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "idee")
public class Idee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String titre;
    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private String theme;

    @Column
    private String type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idee")
    private Collection<Avis> avis;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private Utilisateur user;
```

and this is Avis.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "avis")
public class Avis implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String commentaire;
    @Column
    private int score;

    @Column
    private Boolean signaler;

    @Column
    private Boolean satisfaction_utilisateur;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idee_id")
    private Idee idee;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private Utilisateur user_avis;
```

Comment: use   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) and @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL))

Comment: what error its showing

Comment: this query doesn't shows the resut i am attending to which means it shows all the table avis and i want only the collection<Avis> of a specific Idee .

Comment: have you tried equivalent query on database . check any result is present or not?

Comment: have you tried cascadeType?

Comment: i tried cascadeType . nothing changes . still shows all the table Avis

Comment: in Avis class use id instead of idee_id i.e   @JoinColumn(name = "id").

Comment: in that way the application has in Error while deploying it "Repeating colun in mapping for entity Avis:id <should be mapped with inserrt="false" update="false">

Comment: ok change the name of id of Idee class to idee_id and keep  @JoinColumn(name = "idee_id") as it is.

Comment: yes i do it . so you're thinking that this query is correct : SELECT avis FROM idee i JOIN i.avis avis

Comment: yes it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your query is not working might have to do with the following reasons:

1. In the `FROM` clause you're using wrong entity name, namely `idee`. What you have to use there is either the name of the entity (which you haven't given) or unqualified class name of the entity which is `Idee`.
2. The identification variable you're using for `i.avis` is the same as the entity class name which is not valid according to the specification as the identification variable is case insesitive (`avis == Avis`).

So your query should modified as

```
SELECT a FROM Idee i JOIN i.avis a
```

Comment: i chnaged that way and it works now : List<Avis> resultList = (List<Avis>)this.entityManager.createQuery(" SELECT a FROM idee x JOIN x.avis a where x.id=:ideeId ").setParameter("ideeId", ideeId)
   .getResultList();

Comment: the entity name is Idee but the table name is idee beacuse i am using MySQL database .

Comment: JPQL is similar to SQL but not the same, so table name is not involved in a JP QL query.